# Kurtosis function on image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics

I would like to calculate the Kurtosis of an image in matlab.
**Matlab has a function `kurtosis`**
I can use this function on a matrix. For example:

```
m = rand([4 5]);
kurtosis(m(:));
```

Though when I use this grayscale image: [image]

```
I = imread('0.tiff');
kurtosis(I(:));
```

I get this error:

> Error using  - 
>   Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or
>   scalar doubles.
>
> Error in kurtosis (line 39) x0 = x - repmat(nanmean(x,dim), tile);

My question now is: What am I doing wrong, and how can I calculate the kurtosis of an image.

Comment: Try to output I and see if you have 2D array. And for Tiff file you need second parameter (I think). i.e I=imread('0.tiff',1) etc.

Comment: the variable I is as it should be I think (I can do imshow(I) and see the image). If I output the the image i see values between 0 and 255 , like a grayscale image should be. (Btw the function moment(I(:),2), doesn't work either)

Comment: @ColinTBowers It's from the JAFFE database (http://www.kasrl.org/jaffe.html) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kurtosis needs I to be double. This works:

```
kurtosis(double(I(:)));
```

or this

```
kurtosis(double(I));
```